# Javascript file not loading while running it with socket io

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io

**JS File**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Connecting to web socket
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    // When conection to web socket is established
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        document.querySelectorAll('.clickbtn').forEach(button => {
            button.onclick = () =>{
                const selection = button.dataset.vote;
                socket.emit('submit vote', {'selection':selection})
            };
        });
    });
    // Recieving the data from the server
    socket.on('announce vote', data => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = `Vote Recorded: ${data.selection}`;
        document.querySelector('.votes').append(li);
    });
});
```

**Python file**

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "thisisthesecretkey"
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def votes():
    return render_template("voting.html")


@socketio.on("submit vote")
def index(data):
    selection = data["selection"]
    emit("announce vote", {"selection":selection}, broadcast = True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   socketio.run(app)
```

When i run this file it gives an error in the console on 3 line of the js file, stating **Uncaught ReferenceError io is not defined**. And the error is on the third line where i have made the connection to socket. So is the connection syntax wrong or i am missing something else.

Comment: did you imported the library?

Comment: which library??

Comment: the socketio library, do you use `import` or do you include it with `<script>`

Comment: as you can see i have imported socketio in the python file and not anywhere else

Comment: import it into your js file `<script>https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js</script>`

Comment: this command is giving an error after https: